# when using dcc.Store(), TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using dcc.Store() to share dataframe data between callback. and I got an error of
TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable.  Thanks for your help.

```
@app.callback(
    [
    Output("well-table", "data"),
    ],
    [
    Input('load-area-data','n_clicks'),
    ],
    [
     State("select-area-dropdown", "value"),
     State('read-existing-data-radio','value'),
    ],
    
    prevent_initial_call=True,   # disable output in the first load
)
def change_area_data(n_clicks,area,read_existing_radio): 

...
    s=json.dumps(df_timedata)
    return (datatable_thisarea,
            s, 
           )
TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 2):

This is usually due to collecting/passing/returning a raw dataframe rather than a JSON-compatible version of it which can be serialised. You haven't provided an in-depth error log for this issue, but I highly suspect that you are returning the `df_timedata` incorrectly back to a dash datatable.

In any case, make sure you convert the dataframe using something like [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) which can be serialised and then storing that in a `dcc.Store`. you can reconvert back to a dataframe using [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I use json.dumps(df.to_dict()), then I got another error of TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Timestamp.

Comment: Convert your timestamp to a string before conversion, then back to timestamp when converting back